# React JSX - There are different results for console.log statements in Codepen and what should show in DOM

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

**General problem:**

**There is a difference between the desired results that I see in the console and what I'm seeing in the DOM. If I add a couple of new ToDo component instances inside of a ToDoList component instance and try to delete one, the console will show the correct corresponding results but the DOM will not show the correct updated state.**

So in my Codepen https://codepen.io/flo527/pen/eyjOmw?editors=0011, I have setup a component TodoList that will contain many instances of the functional component ToDo below:

```
const ToDo = props => (
<tr>
<td>
   <label>{props.id}</label>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input />
   </td>
   <td>
    <label>
     {props.createdAt.toTimeString()}
    </label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <span>
      <button onClick = {() =>
  props.removeFromList(props.id)}>
        Remove
      </button>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
);
```

The code that indicates that ToDoList component is encapsulating Todo components:

```
{this.state.list.map(
    (todo, index) => (
       <ToDo key={todo.id}
                 {...todo}
       />
    )
)}
```

I have set up console log statements through out the removeListItem method to explicitly explain which ToDo instance has been clicked on inside of the ToDoList component instance and the state of the variables inside of the removeListItem method.

Comment: Which behavior do you consider unexpected? In which line of the code is console.log not reflecting what you want/see?

Comment: Can you try something simpler to remove the items from the todos list, like list = list.filter(a => a.id !== idToRemove) ?

Comment: Let's say you add a couple of inputs to the list and then delete some. In line 131 of the codepen example I gave you: https://codepen.io/flo527/pen/eyjOmw?editors=0011. The state of the list after it has been set is not reflected in the DOM but is reflected in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read more on React and I found out about the process of reconciliation where React will update the DOM based on the differences between the previous and current in-memory representations of the Virtual DOM. In my code I was trying to discern differences based on the Id and was decrementing the id as well. This is not the proper solution because once I decremented the id, the element in the list before the element with the decremented id had the same id and the problem was the key(the identifier that React uses to detect the uniqueness of an element) was set to id. The solution was to choose a more unique prop to be key, so instead I went with the createdAt prop because no two elements could be created at the same time. This allowed the removeItem method to run more smoothly.

```
 {this.state.list.map(
     (todo, index) => (
         <ToDo
            key={todo.createdAt}
            removeFromList = {this.state.removeFromList}
            {...todo}
         />
      )
 )}
```

More on React Reconciliation: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
removeFromList(index){
   var oldList = this.state.list;

  oldList.filter((item,i)=>{
      return (i != index); // or item.id != ID_PASSED_IN_FUNC
  });
 this.setState({oldList:oldList});
}
```

Instead of doing all looping , better you can use ES6 filter option which will reduce your line of code as well as problem also.